# How to modify parent's DIV content without id in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

How to set bottom layer visible by click on upper layer?

```
<div class="inactive">
    <div> <a href="#" onclick="do visible another parent layer"><img src='images/message.png'></a>

    </div>
    <div style="display:none">!Message need to show!</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
$jq(document).ready(function () {
    $jq('.title').append('<span></span>');
    $jq('.post span').each(function () {
        var trigger = $jq(this),
            state = false,
            el = trigger.parent().next('.entry');
        trigger.click(function () {
            state = !state;
            el.slideToggle();
            trigger.parent().parent().toggleClass('inactive');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: Just traverse the DOM ?

Comment: I have jquery code which worked fine, but after adding new scripts on my page now it's not worked

Comment: <script>
$jq(document).ready(function() {
 $jq('.title').append('<span></span>');
 $jq('.post span').each(function() {
  var trigger = $jq(this), state = false, el = trigger.parent().next('.entry');
  trigger.click(function(){
   state = !state;
   el.slideToggle();
   trigger.parent().parent().toggleClass('inactive');
  });
 });
});
</script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse the DOM up first to get the `div` container, move down to the next sibling (`div`) then display it.

```
<a href="#" onclick="this.parentElement.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.display = 'block';">
    <img src='images/message.png'>
</a>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4a60vvao/)

Comment: It's not working. I meen DIV with style="display:none" not changing Visible to block after click

Comment: @dmitrygolubeu updated. Turns out that the first sibling of a div is its contained text, then the next one is the following node. Cheers.